# c# generic interface where parameter is generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface

```
public interface IOfflineBackedRepo<TSummary,TDetail>
{
    Task SyncAsync();
}
```

this has different concrete implementations. I am trying to develop a service lets developers register different implementations of `IOfflineBackedRepo` interface and separately call `SyncAsync` at a later point in time. The new interface should be similar to the below, except this is not a valid syntax.

```
public interface ISyncManager<T> where T : IOfflineBackedRepo<TSummary, TDetail>
{
    void Register(T repo);

    Task SyncNowAsync(); // this loops through and calls SyncAsync on the repo
}
```

How to fix the syntax issue?

Comment: what is the syntax error?

Comment: The type or namespace TSummary could not be found

Comment: so, doesn't this means, that you need to define `TSummary` somewhere?

Comment: public interface ISyncManager<T,TSummary,TDetail>, enjoy

Answer (score 1):

`ISyncManager` does not have anywhere mentioning `TSummary,TDetail` in it's scope

`TSummary` and `TDetail` is defined and exist only around `IOfflineBackedRepo`. When you try to use it anywhere else you must define a type you will use in substitute for them. It could be actual type or a type that you would get from generic argument but you must define it somewhere around `ISyncManager`

At the most basic ways,

```
public interface ISyncManager<T,U,V> where T : IOfflineBackedRepo<U,V>
{
    void Register(T repo);

    Task SyncNowAsync(); // this loops through and calls SyncAsync on the repo
}
```

For the ease of use I think you should just separate interface

```
public interface IOfflineBackedRepo
{
    Task SyncAsync(); // this function is not typed specific right?
}

public interface IOfflineBackedRepo<TSummary,TDetail> : IOfflineBackedRepo
{
    // other definition about type specific
}

public interface ISyncManager<T> where T : IOfflineBackedRepo
{
    void Register(T repo);

    Task SyncNowAsync(); // this loops through and calls SyncAsync on the repo
}
```

And I guess `ISyncManager` is actually just a collection. I think it would be better if you could just make extension method for collection

```
public static class SyncManagerExt
{
    // Register is just Add to collection
    public static Task SyncNowAsync(this ICollection<T> items) where T : IOfflineBackedRepo
    {
        // loops through items and calls SyncAsync on the repo
    }
}
```